# Conditionally assign a series or na to a variable

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to switch On/Off a security call which brings back three series which are assigned to a tuple.

The tuple [h_01, l_01, c_01] is assigned to either series from a security call or [na, na, na], based on a bool value inputted by the user. Code below:

```
sy_01 = input(defval = "BINANCE:BTCUSDT", title = "Symbol 01", type = input.symbol)
bl_01 = input(defval = true, title = "On/Off", type = input.bool)

[h_01, l_01, c_01] = bl_01 ? security(sy_01, resolution = "", expression = [high, low, close]) : [na, na, na]
```

I get an error.

I also tried using the format below:

```
bl_01 ? [h_01, l_01, c_01] = security(sy_01, resolution = "", expression = [high, low, close]) : [h_01, l_01, c_01] = [na, na, na]
```

I also tried `iff(condition, then, _else)`, and an `if else block`. I also tried assigning to [0, 0, 0] or [1, 1, 1] instead of [na, na, na]. I also tried to write the condition as `bl_01 == true`.  Nothing works.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f_boolTuple(_high, _low, _close, _on) =>
    _h = _on ? _high : na
    _l = _on ? _low : na
    _c = _on ? _close : na
    [_h, _l, _c]

[h_01, l_01, c_01] = security(sy_01, resolution = "", expression = f_boolTuple(high, low, close, bl_01))
```

Tuples can only be returned from functions and can't be directly assigned, this is for example invalid in Pine :

```
[h, l] = [high, low]
```

or in your case this part of your ternary is invalid if `bl_01` is false

```
[h_01, l_01, c_01] = [na, na, na]
```

`security()` is a built in function that can return tuples. But because you can't directly assign `[na, na, na]` to your tuples you have to perform your logic in a different context.

By performing the logic check within a function (which CAN return the `[na, na, na]` tuple), we can then use this function as the expression in the `security()` call.

Comment: A little explanation why OP code doesn't work and yours will would be helpful for current and future readers with similar problem. If possible please add 1-2 sentences at least.